# Rails: ActiveRecord custom average calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Outside of using a raw SQL query, is there a nice way to divide an active record query result by a constant? A variable?

Example:

```
Phones.group(:year).order(:year).average(:talk_time_min)
```

If I wanted to retrieve the `talk_time_min` in seconds, how could I do `talk_time_min / 60`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Phones.group(:year).order(:year).average('talk_time_min/60')
```

Comment: yeah, I deleted that comment just in case